# Is a Flying-sign (panhandling) "bet" legit?

Tags: halacha, tzedakah-charity, gambling

A flying-sign panhandler had a sign that read:

> I bet you $1 you won't read this [sign](http://www.vice.com/read/how-cardboard-signs-changed-the-face-of-panhandling-in-america-518).

I thought it was clever and humorous so I gave him $1 and wished him well.

By giving him $1 did I accept the transaction as a bet? Or does it remain an act of charity?

Comment: "Stipulate" What does that even mean here? I don't see how he could have forced you to do anything so it seems clear you gave out of the goodness of your heart, which if your job. Let God figure out the rest.

Comment: How could there be a transaction without consent? There is no bet, and that's the joke here. You gave him a dollar because you got a kick out of his joke.